# How can i implement multi websites in one core in django?

Tags: django, django-3.2

How can I implement multi websites with one core in Django?
I have multi websites with this structure:

```
example.com   (Main website)
example.com/subdirectory1  (Second website)
example.com/subdirectory2  (Third website)
example.com/subdirectory2/en  (Fourth website)
example.com/subdirectory3  (Fifth website)
```

I want to use one core and one database to manage all websites.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to take a look to the "sites" framwork integrated in Django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/sites/

it will allow you to connect many databases to one django project install according to the URL you are calling.